# NSSLider Set Starting Value

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsslider

I'm trying to get my NSSlider to start at a certain value, and I've been unable to find function to do that in the swift book or other resources. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first create an outlet for your NSSlider:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourSlider: NSSlider!
```

then you just have to set it's initial value as follow:

```
yourSlider.doubleValue = 0.5
```